# Дельфи не видит объект на форме и говорит Undeclared Identifier

Tags: delphi

Дельфи в упор не видит таймеры, которые я создал... Он видит форму и имжйдж, но при попытке использовать таймер говорит, что его нет (Undeclared identifier:TimerSpawn). Вот код:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
ClassPanzer=class(TObject)
x,y,hp:integer;
Bmp:TBitmap;
end;
  TFormGame = class(TForm)
    ImageGround: TImage;
    TimerSpawn: TTimer;
    Timer2: TTimer;
    Timer3: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormGame: TFormGame;
  PanzerFaust:array of ClassPanzer;
  PanzerToRight,PanzerToUp,PanzerToLeft,PanzerToDown,BitMapGround,BitMapRoad,BitMapBaseSovjet,BitMapBaseNazi:TBitmap;
  WaveCount,Gold:integer;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormGame.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var Counter1:integer;
begin
//
PanzerToRight.Free;
PanzerToUp.Free;
PanzerToLeft.Free;
PanzerToDown.Free;
BitMapGround.Free;
BitMapRoad.Free;
BitMapBaseSovjet.Free;
BitMapBaseNazi.Free;
//
for Counter1:=1 to Length(PanzerFaust) do PanzerFaust[Counter1].Free;
//
end;

procedure TFormGame.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var counter1,counter2, counter3 :integer;
begin
// procedure begin
counter3:=1;
PanzerToRight:=TBitmap.Create;
PanzerToRight.LoadFromFile('PanzerToRight.bmp');
//
PanzerToUp:=TBitmap.Create;
PanzerToUp.LoadFromFile('PanzerToUp.bmp');
//
PanzerToLeft:=TBitmap.Create;
PanzerToLeft.LoadFromFile('PanzerToLeft.bmp');
//
PanzerToDown:=TBitmap.Create;
PanzerToDown.LoadFromFile('PanzerToDown.bmp');
//
BitMapGround:=TBitmap.Create;
BitMapGround.LoadFromFile('Ground.bmp');
//
BitMapRoad:=TBitmap.Create;
BitMapRoad.LoadFromFile('Road.bmp');
//
BitMapBaseSovjet:=TBitmap.Create;
BitMapBaseSovjet.LoadFromFile('SovjetBase.bmp');
//
BitmapBaseNazi:=TBitmap.Create;
BitMapBaseNazi.LoadFromFile('NaziBase.bmp');
for   counter1:=1 to 20 do for counter2:= 1 to 20 do ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(counter2*50-50,counter1*50-50,BitMapGround);
//
for   counter1:=1 to 10 do for counter2:= 1 to 20 do ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(Counter2*50-50,counter1*100-50,BitMapRoad);
//
counter3:=100;
for counter1:=1 to 5 do begin
ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(950,counter3,BitMapRoad);
counter3:=counter3+200;
end;
//
counter3:=200;
for counter1:=1 to 4 do begin
ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(0,counter3,BitMapRoad);
counter3:=counter3+200;
end;
//
ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(0,050,BitMapBaseNazi);
ImageGround.Canvas.Draw(0,950,BitMapBaseSovjet);
//
WaveCount:=1;
//procedure end
end;
//
procedure WaveStart;
var SpawnCounter,Counter1:integer;
begin
// procedure begin
SpawnCounter:=WaveCount*50 div 4;
Setlength(PanzerFaust,SpawnCounter);
//
for Counter1 := 1 to SpawnCounter do begin
PanzerFaust[Counter1]:=ClassPanzer.Create;
PanzerFaust[Counter1].x:=50;
PanzerFaust[Counter1].y:=50;
PanzerFaust[Counter1].hp:=100;
PanzerFaust[Counter1].Bmp:=PanzerToRight;
TimerSpawn.Enabled:=True;
end;
// procedure end
end;

end.
```

Что я делаю не так???
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А вообще общий совет. 1) Используйте форматирование 2) Разбивайте код на процедуры. Чтобы выглядело не кусками текста, а названиями процедур.  Вместо PanzerToRight:=TBitmap.Create;
PanzerToRight.LoadFromFile('PanzerToRight.bmp');  Написать процедуру CreateAndLoadBitmapFromFile...

Comment: Время будет затрачено, но самое главное, что легче отлаживать ошибки (а в коде с тысячами строк это полная шляпа) и код будет понятнее и читабельнее (особенно, если заглянуть через год, два, три... разобраться довольно сложно)

Comment: Спасаибо... таймер видеть начал.... однако не получается вызвать процедуру WaveStart

Comment: WaveStart  как классовая процедура? Если нет, перенесите её в самое начало модуля. Но лучше как классовую процедуру описать. Я конечно сильно код не изучал, но еще попробуйте переделать классы. Чтобы методы классов были внутри класса, а не отдельной процедурой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут два варианта:

1. Либо сделать `procedure WaveStart;` членом класса (т.е. `procedure TFormGame.WaveStart;`), чтобы виделся таймер, так как он является членом класса `TFormGame`
2. Либо указать экземпляр класса к которому этот таймер принадлежит `FormGame.TimerSpawn`

Предпочтительнее не использовать глобальные переменные, это чревато путаницей и усложнит дальнейшую отладку. Желательно спроектировать классы учитывая поведение объектов. Добавить методы отрисовки/перерисовки объекта, а также инициализации.

Comment: поскольку в delphi есть отдельный термин классовых методов/конструкторов и т.п., которые выглядят как `class procedure ...` то формулировать мысли лучше в виде "сделать членом класса", а не "сделать классовой"